# Remove all ImageViews using Tag

Tags: android

how does one iterate through a view's children and remove all ImageViews with a Tag that StartsWith a particular string?
All examples I can find this iterator;

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < mat.getChildCount(); pos++)
    {
        Object tag = mat.getChildAt(pos).getTag();
        if (tag != null)
        {
            String s = tag.toString();
            if (s.startsWith("Z"))
            {
                mat.removeView(mat.getChildAt(pos));
            }
        }
    }
```

do a test, then remove the object. 
The issue is both 'pos' and getChildCount change throughout the process. If I want to remove the first item and then the 2nd item (which after the first remove is actually the first item) it won't work, as pos is now 1 (ie 2nd item).

thanks

Comment: Start with the last child, and decrement down to the first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

```java
for (int pos = 0; pos < mat.getChildCount();) {
    if (remove) {
        mat.removeViewAt(pos);
        continue;
    }
    // only increment if the element wasn't removed
    pos++;
}
```

```java
for (int pos = 0; pos < mat.getChildCount(); pos++) {
    if (remove) {
        mat.removeViewAt(pos);
        // balance out the next increment
        pos--;
    }
}
```

```java
// don't remove views until after iteration
List<View> removeViews = new ArrayList<>();
for (int pos = 0; pos < mat.getChildCount(); pos++) {
    if (remove) {
        removeViews.add(mat.getChildAt(pos));
    }
}
for (View view : removeViews) {
    mat.removeView(view);
}
```

```java
// count in reverse
for (int pos = mat.getChildCount() - 1; pos >= 0; pos--) {
    if (remove) {
        mat.removeViewAt(pos);
    }
}
```